# Finding the number of form elements

Tags: jquery, html

What is the possible way of finding the total number of form elements using jquery? 
To be clear, here is the code

```
 <html>
     <body>
        <form>
        <div>
            Name
            <input type="text" class="name">
        </div>

        <div class="radioselect">
            Yes
            <input type="radio" name="same" class="radio">
            NO
            <input type="radio" name="same" class="radio">
        </div>
        <div>
            Comment
            <textarea class="area"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

In the above code, consider we need to find the number of form elements. By simple jquery, we can use the script like this:

```
$('input').length;
$('textarea').length;
```

By this way we can find the total number of individual form elements. Suppose if we need to find the total number of such form elements for a dynamic form, what is the possible way of doing it? Because we cannot easily detect the type of form element present in them? Suggest me a possible way for this problem

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: The easy approach is to concatenate the selectors: `$('input,textarea,button,select')` However, it sounds like **your** definition of a form element differs from the W3C meaning. Can you explain with with **individual form elements**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Amine hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189392/finding-the-number-of-form-elements/18189487#comment26653672_18189392), use the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

```js
$(':input').length
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count all form elements, use this tag:

```
$('form').find('input, textarea, select').length;
```

or

```
elementTypes = ['input', 'textarea', 'select'];
$.each(elementTypes, function(index, _el) {
    $(_el).length;
});
```

Comment: My need is not to find the exact number of elements for the present form. As I said so, the actual form is dynamic. In such problem, how can we count the length?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by dynamic, because everytime you add an element to the form, you can use length again.

Comment: Form creation should be done dynamically. So in such cases, we don't know what form element and how many of them are added. What can we do in that case?

Comment: form elements can only be input, textarea or select, so this answer is correct, you use this selector to find out how many input elements there are within any given form no matter how the inputs were created

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I can well under your answer now.Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(":input").length;` should give the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is question is old but maybe I can provide an answer for newbies that can help. Normally, well-defined form elements have a name attribute. Instead of counting the elements by using their types, it would be more accurate to use a common attribute. In this case, `var n = $('form [name]').length;` is quite sufficient to count every single element in the form. I assume you want to count radio elements individually, not as a whole. Instead, you will have to exclude them. Of course, you can use the form ID instead of form tag if you need to.